# Implementing React in Electron application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron, jsx

I've been struggling implementing very simple react code in my electron desktop application.
If I execute the app, there is no error message, but only empty page.
I tried changing script type as "text/babel" as well, but still the output is empty.
Can someone tell me what's the reason?

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="react_root"></div>
      <script type ="text/jsx" src="./renderer.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

renderer.jsx

```
const React = require('react');
const { createRoot } = require('react-dom/client');
function App() {
    return <h1>Hello, World!</h1>;
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("react_root"));
root.render(React.createElement(App));
```

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "tester",
  "license": "NA",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "13.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.17",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "frames-react": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-devtools": "^4.28.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-frame-component": "^5.2.6",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

if I try to add something more tags (ex. ..etc) in App()'s return I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error. This is also the part I can't understand..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your dependencies you have [`react-scripts`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts), which means you created your React app using [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/). The latter is supposed to come with several scripts to use your app, but they seem to be missing here. I will answer your question given your current configuration, but you should know that **[CRA is no longer maintained](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487#issuecomment-1409720741)**.

##### Add the scripts to `package.json`

When in development, you need to first start the dev server to run your React app, and then to start Electron. To do that, you can use the modules [`wait-on`](https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on) and [`concurrently`](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently). In your `package.json`, add the following scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:react": "react-scripts start",
  "start:electron": "electron .",
  "start": "concurrently \"npm start:react\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000/ && npm start:electron\""
}
```

You will be able to start the app for dev with:

```bash
npm run start
```

If you use `yarn` instead of `npm`, update the scripts accordingly. If you want to know what are the other available `react-scripts`'s scripts, you can see the list [in the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/).

##### Remove the script from `index.html`

CRA will automatically inject the app script into the `index.html`, but the file **has to be named `index.js` and should be into a `src` folder**, [this is required for CRA to work](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/).

```html
<body>
  <div id="react_root"></div>
  <!-- <script type ="text/jsx" src="./renderer.jsx"></script> <- Remove this -->
</body>
```

##### Load the file in Electron window

When you are in development, you should load your `index.html` from the dev server URL (default to `http://localhost:3000/`), while in production, you should load the file directly (from the `build` folder gererated with CRA when you [build the app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/)).

```js
app.isPackaged
  ? mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"))
  : mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
```

##### Additional notes for production

In your `package.json`, you need to [add the `homepage` property](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson) for your app to work correctly in prod:

```json
 "homepage": "./"
```

And if you use a router such as [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main), you should use a [hash router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router), since [browser router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) will not work with Electron.

---

##### What if you don't want to use CRA?

Well, the logic remains the same, you should have a dev server running that you use to load your app in dev. And you should bundle ("build") your files for production. You can either configure everything by yoursef using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) (or another similar tool), or you can use a boilerplate or a template. **In any case, make sure to read the documentations of the tools you use (especially [React](https://react.dev/) and [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/)), and to do more research before asking a question.**